# What does the gold beam above a Foundable mean?

Tags: wizards-unite

In *Wizards Unite*, there will occasionally be a gold beam that shoots from the Foundables that appear on the map.

At first I thought it meant to be Foundable that I had not yet encountered before. However, that theory ended up bring proved wrong after I encountered one of these and it ended up being a Foundable I had already encountered.

So, what does this gold beam mean?

[image: Foundable with gold beam]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to this [video](https://youtu.be/IjKLCd4OKfM?t=42) (starting at 42 seconds), it indicates the difficulty of the Foundable

> Yellow = Medium
>
> Orange = Severe
>
> Red = Emergency

Also, if you view this [link](https://www.imore.com/harry-potter-wizards-unite-tips-and-tricks) it says the following:

> Keep your eyes peeled for a beam of light shooting up from the Traces
> you see in the world, these are high-risk Foundables, and as such are
> worthy of your time.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that indicates a more difficult Foundable. There are also red beams which indicate an even higher difficulty.